# OpenNI camera parameters gives faulty marker detection

Tags: ros, kinect, marker, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone

Following my problem with getting the camera parameters from the [OpenNi driver](http://answers.ros.org/question/299/getting-the-calibration-parameters-of-the-kinect#1136) which is now solved, then I have set up [ArToolKitPlus](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar/artoolkitplus.php) to detect markers using the RGB camera with the parameters from "rgb/camera_info". I have previously used the ArToolKitPlus in another project where it worked fine, but this time I experienced some problems with the distance in the z-axis.
I have used rviz to compare the frame of the marker with the RGB point cloud, the marker frame has "openni_rgb_optical_frame". Screenshots of this is can be seen [here](http://i51.tinypic.com/2ilndat.png) and [here](http://i55.tinypic.com/rup8pc.png), there square marker might be a bit hard to see, but it looks like the found marker fits regarding the x- and y-position, but the depth is totally off. The question is why the depth is failing using ArToolKitPlus, I am have also tried to do manual calibration of the camera and getting more or less the same parameters, so the problem must be something internal in the Kinect camera. Maybe something originating from the [depth sensing](http://media.bestofmicro.com/,M-E-283334-3.jpg)?

I hope someone has an idea to solve this problem as marker detection is crucial for two of my projects.

Regards

Sebastian Aslund

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9748/openni-camera-parameters-gives-faulty-marker-detection/) by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2011-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2011-04-16**:
I have done some further testing, it seems that the further the marker is away from the camera, the higher is the error in the depth. 16cm away from the camera is the error 7cm, 40cm away is the error 15cm and 80cm away the error is 28cm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would suggest that your intrinsic calibration for the rbg camera is incorrect.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0